# Vectorspace subspace proof

Tags: vector-spaces

V is $n$ dimensional vectorspace over $\mathbb{R}$. $W\subset V$ is $m$ dimensional subspace over $\mathbb{R}$ and  $m < n$.
$$Y=\bigcap \{U:U \text{ is a subspace of} \ V, \dim U=n-1, W \subset U \}$$

Prove that $Y=W$.

I could use some help on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $W ⊂ Y$ trivially. Then note that you can extend a base of $W$ to a base of $V$ and leave out one of the adjoined base vectors to obtain a subspace $U ⊂ V$ of dimension $n-1$.

Comment: @user140831 Actually, I don’t think this answers the question entirely and I’m not sure if I thought of the whole solution when posting this. Maybe I was a bit confused. And maybe you’ve already done the rest, but if not, let me add: *Any* (non-zero) vector not contained in $W$ can be used to extend the base as the one to be left out later on. This proves $W^c ⊂ Y^c$.